# MySQL table data comparision

Tags: mysql

Due to some requirement i am moving data from mysql to other database which is also mysql compatible. Here, the mapping is pretty much 1:1 and few columns might be different.
I need to run a query to compare the data column by column and get the rows with column name for which the data is not matching. Using a tool which can connect to 2 diff database and query.

```
select * from db1.table1 s, db2.table1 t where s.col1 != t.col1 OR s.col2 != t.col2
```

Here, Need to join two tables based on the join condition and then compare column values which is not matching.

Comment: I would use [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html).

Comment: This is just an example. I am syncing data from MySQL to some other analytical data store and trying to build data reconciliation.

Comment: Ah, unless this mysterious unnamed data store supports MySQL protocol, the pt-table-sync tool will not work. You may be forced to develop this data comparison tool yourself if no tool exists that can connect to both MySQL and the other data store. In any case, no one can recommend a solution if you don't specify which product the other datastore is.

Comment: My question is about query to compare data. I am good with syncing data

Comment: That's why I suggested pt-table-sync. It has to compare data in order to identify the minimal data that needs to be synced. The tool has options to make it compare, but skip the sync part, only report the data it would have synced.

Comment: Good to know. Will it work for oracle to redshift as welll?

Comment: No, as I said above, it supports MySQL protocol. There are a few other brands of database that use that protocol (for example MariaDB and TiDB). Oracle has its own protocol. Redshift is based on PostgreSQL so I assume it supports that product's protocol. You said in your question that the other database was MySQL compatible, but I guess it is not.

Comment: Why do you think that the data might not be faithfully transferred?

Answer (score 0):

> Using a tool which can connect to 2 diff database and query... SELECT ... FROM ...

That is essentially impossible.

Instead, write a program that connects to the two databases, does a `SELECT` against each database, pulls the data back, and does the comparison in your program (not in SQL).

MySQL, MariaDB, and Percona are compatible enough to be considered the "same". but if you throw anything else in that mix, then you are unlikely to find an off-the-shelf product to help.

Another approach:

On each server, export the data to a CSV file (by whatever tool is available to that specific db), then compare the ascii files generated (On Linux, use `diff`.)

Comment: We have trinodb which can connect to multiple data source and join data using sql.

Comment: "Select from 2 diff data sources" is available only through FederatedX or Spider when using MariaDB.  But it may not be fast.  If it is a large amount of data, then my export suggestion may be warranted.